# Dynamic memory re-allocation in custom vector class

Tags: c++11, memory-management

How I understand, every time when I use word `new` I must use `delete` , for avoiding memory leaks. In my example, in `push_back()` ,I use `new` for re-allocating dynamic memory to my vector. I think, that every time when I use `push_back()`, I allocate a new part of memory and dont `delete` old. If I right, can someone explain me, how I should delete my memory, for saving values in with theirs adresses. If i wrong, please, explain my why?

```
 class Vector {
        double* ptr;
        size_t size;
        size_t max_size;
        public:
        Vector(): size{0}, max_size{1} {
            ptr = new double(max_size);
        }
        ~Vector(){
            delete pointer;
        }
        void push_back(const double elem) {
            if (size+1 == max_size) {
                double* buf_ptr = ptr;
                max_size*=2;
                ptr = new double(max_size);
            }
            ptr[size] = elem;
            size+=1;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Note that `new double(max_size)` doesn't allocate an array, it allocates a single double that has the value `max_size`. To allocate an array: `new double[max_size]`. And to deallocate that array: `delete[]`, not `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. You want to use `new double[maxsize]` (allocate array of doubles), not `new double(maxsize)` (allocate single double value)
2. After the new allocation succeed, you want to copy data from the old array (e.g. [with `std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)), or you'll drop the old data on the floor
3. Once you've succesfully allocated the new array and copied the old data, `delete[] buf_ptr` to release the old array's memory

All of that can be fixed by replacing this line:

```
            ptr = new double(max_size);
```

with these lines:

```
            ptr = new double[max_size];
            std::copy(buf_ptr, buf_ptr + size, ptr);
            delete[] buf_ptr;
```

Make sure to `#include <algorithm>` for [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) at the top of your source file.

Note: You'd need to adjust your constructor and destructor use matching array based forms of `new` and `delete` respectively.

Comment: I dont use std::copy, and it works without "dropping the old data on the floor". Maybe i misunderstood you.

Comment: Okay, I understand) Can I use loop where I will copy data, instead using std::copy?

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko: Of course you can, but why reinvent the wheel? `std::copy` should compile down to the same (or very similar) machine code as the loop (possibly better than the loop if you implement the loop unusually badly), and it makes the intent of your code immediately obvious; self-documenting code is a good thing.